# System.currentTimeMillis() is acting weird

Tags: java

Here is my code block to show the weirdness.
I'm comparing two times in milli seconds. Time t1 is in milliseconds after 74 days and time t2 is in milliseconds after 90 days. My expectation is t1 < t2, but actually it shows t1 is greater than t2. It prints **FAILED** on the console. Same code runs fine in Javascript as expected.

```java
class CompareDates {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()+(74*24*60*60*1000);
    long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis()+(90*24*60*60*1000);
    if(t1 <= t2 ) {
      System.out.println("PASSED");
    } else {
      System.out.println("FAILED");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also: `TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(74)` would be a lot more readable, and correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`74*24*60*60*1000` overflows `int`. To prevent it, add `L` to the first operand in order to do every multiplication in `long`: `74L*24*60*60*1000`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked :)

Comment: As a general comment, it's worth putting the `L` on the first number, in order to ensure that you're not overflowing before the end as well: `74*24*60*60` *doesn't* overflow, but some other calculation might.

Comment: @AndyTurner Good point, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: If it worked, you should accept the answer to give the answerer credit.

Comment: Thanks @JWoodchuck. Missed it.